# Webpack library re-export

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have 2 libraries A and B.

- A is bundled using webpack in a first pass then published to a npm repository and later consumed by B. A contains let's say a class MyA.
- B depends on A among other libraries and all libraries are bundled together in B (=> A is bundled in B).
- B should re-export certain parts of A (e.g. MyA) to make them visible to the outside world.

In `webpack.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
     'b': ['./src/MyB.js', './js/a.js']
```

In `a.js` (compiled by webpack) I have:

```
var mya = 
.... 
function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
   var MyA_1 = __webpack_require__(1);
   exports.MyA = MyA_1.MyA;
}
```

In `b.js` bundle I end up with:

```
function(module, exports) {
   // here we are in MyB
   var a = new MyA(); // this is not found, even if prefixed with mya
},
function(module, exports) {
   // a.js code is bundled with b in b.js
   var mya = ...
   // missing: exports.MyA = mya;
}
```

And of course MyA is not visible anywhere outside.
Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: try to switch entries order 'b': ['./src/a.js', './js/MyB.js']

Comment: This doesn't help. Unfortunately what is missing is something like `exports.MyA = mya;` in the final `b.js` bundle. And also something like `var MyA_1 = __webpack_require__(2);` where MyA is used. Otherwise how can B (the code that uses MyA) know about `MyA`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array for your entry points, why not use B as your entry, and in it, `require` the A library? Then you can use it, export it, make it global, whatever you need.

Comment: It's actually a bit more complicated in reality because I'm also using Typescript behind the scene.